# Optimization problem on infinite dimensional space

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I want to maximize the function
$$u(a)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty r^i\log a_i$$
defined on some proper subset of $V=\{a\in R^\infty:|\sum r^ia_i|<\infty\}$ for some fixed $r\in (0,1)$.

In particular, let
$D\subset V$ such that
$$a\in D \iff |\sum _{i=0}^{\infty}r^i\log a_i|<\infty  $$
and for fixed $M \in R$, define
$S \subset V$ such that 
$$a\in S \iff \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^ia_i  \leq M$$
I want to solve the following problem
$$max_{a\in S \cap D} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^i\log a_i$$

I want to apply the lagrangian method to this problem. But I am worried about whether it is legitimate to use the lagrangian method and also worried about the existence and uniqueness of the solution. That is,
let
$$
L=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^i\log a_i+\lambda(M-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^ia_i)$$
Carelessly applying the lagrangian method gives the FOC of 
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial a_i}=r^i(a_i^{-1}-\lambda)=0$$
Hence we get $$a_0=a_1=...$$
Combined with the constraint $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^ia_i=M$$
the above equalities give 
$$a_i=(1-r)M$$ 
Can this solution justified? Any hint would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I solved it.
It is obvious that the constraint $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^ia_i=M$$
should hold.

Claim: If $M>0,$ then $a=(1-r)M$ is the unique solution.

Proof:
Let $b$ be the sequence such that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^ib_i=M$ and $b\neq a. $ Then, there must exist $n,m\in N$ such that $n \neq m$ and 
$b_n>(1-r)M, \ ~ b_m<(1-r)M$.
Take $\epsilon _n,  \epsilon _m>0$ such that $r^n\epsilon _n=r^m\epsilon _m$

Define $c_n=b_n-\epsilon_n, c_m=b_m+\epsilon _m, c_k=b_k$ for $k\neq n,m$.
Then, $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^i\log c_i-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^i\log b_i=r^n[\log(b_n-\epsilon_n)-\log(b_n)]+r^m[\log(b_m+\epsilon_m)-\log(b_m)]$$
If we devide both sides by $r^n\epsilon_n=r^m\epsilon_m$ and take $\epsilon_n\rightarrow0$, we have $-b_n^{-1}+b_m^{-1}$. Since we have chosen $n,m$ that satisfiy $b_n>b_m$, it follows that $-b_n^{-1}+b_m^{-1}>0$.
This shows that $u(a)\geq u(c) > u(b)$.